# Evaluating the value of the norm of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am trying to show:
$$\|f_\alpha \|  = \| \alpha \|_{\ell^\infty} $$
Given that:
$$f_\alpha:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \quad f_\alpha = \alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2$$

($\mathbb{R^2}$ is equiped with the $\|.\|_\infty$)

I am struggling to get passed the definition of the operator norm:

$$\|f\|= \sup \limits_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\\ \|x\|_{\ell^\infty} = 1}} |\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 | = \sup \limits_{\substack{x \in \mathbb{R}^2\\ x \neq 0}} \frac{ |\alpha_1 x_1 + \alpha_2 x_2 |}{\|x \|_{\ell^\infty}}$$
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Is $\alpha =(\alpha_1,\alpha_2)$?

Comment: @herbsteinberg yes!

Comment: I don't think this is true. Let $\alpha=(1,2)$. Then $\|\alpha\|_\infty=2$. However, note that for any $x \in \Bbb{R}^2$ with $\|x\|_{\infty}=1$, we have $|f_\alpha(x)| = |x_1+2x_2| \leq 3$ and $|f_\alpha(1,1)|=3$. Thus, $\|f_\alpha\|=3 > 2 = \|\alpha\|_\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Alonso Delfín mentioned, the desired conclusion is wrong. Actually this question is related to the so-called dual norm. By Hölder inequality, for $a,x\in\mathbb{R}^n$, there holds
$$
\sum |a_ix_i|\leq\|a\|_{\ell^p}\|x\|_{\ell^q},
$$
where $p^{-1}+q^{-1}=1$ for $1\leq p,q\leq\infty$ and for each $p,q$ and $a$ there exists $x$ establishing the equality. Therefore we have
$$
\|\langle a,\cdot\rangle\|_{\ell^p}=\|a\|_{\ell^q},
$$
and that's why it is called the dual norm. As your case, it actually should be
$$
\|\langle a,\cdot\rangle\|_{\ell^\infty}=\|a\|_{\ell^1}.
$$